# how to prove this integral

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

Could you tell me how to prove this,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \tanh \left(\frac{x}{a}\right) e^{2 i b x}\frac{dx}{x^2}=-\frac{a} {2}\sum_{x_n>0} \frac{4 \pi i}{x_n^2} e^{-2 b x_n}$$
 where ($x_{n}=\pi a (2n+1))$

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $x_n$?  What have you tried?

Comment: ($x_{n}=a\pi (2n+1))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $\tanh$ has simple poles on the imaginary axis, and their residue matches your RHS.